# Why put on hold by Dave and DavidPostill?

Tags: discussion

This is my question [Saving website leads to incomplete save. Flagged as off topic but i think It is software realted, or in which stackexchange should i ask this instead?](https://superuser.com/questions/1225784/saving-website-leads-to-incomplete-save-flagged-as-off-topic-but-i-think-it-is)

Can someone tell me why is it off topic? Its related to software (Browser) or in which stack community should I ask this??

Comment: Your question has been answered in the comments. Both of the websites you mention are not designed to be saved locally. Why they have been designed that way is off-topic.

Comment: (I could not edited my comment so i added new)

Since these sites were not designed to local save, which tool did web archive used to save them in a better way than i can? And if  any special tools were used and they were saved as only basic save, why cant i download it if im trying to do the same that web archive did?

Comment: One of the my comments contains a link to httrack they likely used a similar software or, as it's kind of what they do, wrote their own tool to do it. It's likely that they automated the process. At a high level the process involves doing a "basic save" of every individual page of the site and afterwards editing the source code of each of those saves to refer to your local copies. You can totally do the same thing but it takes a lot of effort. For simple pages tools like httrack would be able to help you out but with dynamic content you're usually reaching some kind of dead end.

Comment: Thank you very much Seth

Answer (score 5):

> I cannot see the real difference between meta and not meta

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223746/201411

Also, you already asked this question [here](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12526/144607) just a few hours ago. Stop asking the same question over and over. We already provided you all the explanation you need in the comments to your other question.

The question you asked on Super User is off-topic because you are asking a question about *websites* (specific ones, in fact). Super User is about local computer programs on users' systems and general computer know-how (this is not a complete list of Super User on-topic material, but it gives you an idea).

Lastly, if the website you are trying to save has any server-side dynamic code, it is literally impossible to "save" that site with full fidelity to your computer, unless you had direct administrative access to the server running that website. That's just a fact about how the Web works and has nothing to do with any specific piece of technology. It's a simple fact.

Obtaining administrative access to a server legally (e.g., by having an established business relationship with the owner of the site, and convincing them to give you access) is fine, and would enable you to write some scripts and get the data you need, but obtaining it illegally will not be discussed on Super User. And there is **NO** workaround, so stop asking.